# Change the color of href link on click server side

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can some please let me know how to change the color of hyper link.

```
<ul style="align-content:center">
<li>
    <a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a>
</li>
<li><a id="ETL_Perf" onclick="javascript:if (ValidateIsDCSelected()){return SetHref(this.id, 'Reports.aspx', '1', 'Task1', 'ETL Performance-All DCs')}" href="#" class="CssClass1">ETL Performance-All DCs</a></li>

<li><a id="ETL_Status" onclick="javascript:if (ValidateIsDCSelected()){return SetHref(this.id, 'Reports.aspx', '2', 'Task2', 'ETL Status-All DCs')}" href="#" class="CssClass1">ETL Status-All DCs</a></li>

<li><a id="Open_Status" onclick="javascript:if (ValidateIsDCSelected()){return SetHref(this.id, 'Reports.aspx', '3', 'Task3', 'Open Pick Status-All DCs')}" href="#" class="CssClass1">Open Pick Status-All DCs</a></li>

<li><a id="TM_PM" onclick="javascript:if (ValidateIsDCSelected()){return SetHref(this.id, 'Reports.aspx', '4', 'Task4', 'Task,Print Manager and Task Manager ORA : check-All DCs')}" href="#" class="CssClass1">Task,Print Manager Status-All DCs</a></li>

<li class="auto-style18"><a id="PICKS_Hour" onclick="javascript:if (ValidateByoneDC()){return SetHref(this.id, 'Reports.aspx', '5', 'Task5', 'Picks Per Hour Data')}" href="#">Picks Per Hour </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I want to change the color of after calling Reports.aspx 
ETL Status-All DCs
Open Pick Status-All DCs
Task,Print Manager Status-All DCs
Picks Per Hour

Comment: Is this MVC or WebForms. Do you want to use AJAX or refresh the entire page?

Comment: Yes, its Web form , i am suing AJAX

Comment: OT an "onclick" always contains javascript code, so you don't need a "javascript:" prefix

Comment: The color of a link is a CSS issue. Can you add a specific class (that specifies your "used" color) to the link? Depending on how long you want to maintain that color (should it still be there when I visit that page tomorrow?), you may need to remember that "used" status server-side in some way.

Comment: if i use java script client side validation then after on page load new color getting disappear and showing old color .

Comment: Yes right Hans, i need server side code, so that i can write code on page load of Reports.cs

Comment: See following : https://htmlcolorcodes.com/tutorials/html-link-color/